# Ansible - VMWARE

Tags: ansible, vmware

I am in the process of developping an Ansible role to delete VMWARE snapshots.
However, as it might be easy to deleted all of them I want to get rid of those which name match a specific string and are older than x days.

In order to achieve that goal, I first collect snapshots details for each VM using the vmware_guest_snapshot_info collection. This is the easy part.
I register the output in a variable (not sure how it is defined Ansible wise).
I end up with the following dictionary:

```
{"changed": false, 
"guest_snapshots": 
{
 "current_snapshot": 
  {"creation_time": "2023-06-06T18:31:37.532826+00:00", 
   "description": "Snapshot TEST", 
   "id": 1243,    
   "name": "Patching_Linux2023-06-06", 
   "state": "poweredOff"
  }, 
  "snapshots": [
   {"creation_time": "2023-06-06T14:38:17.909158+00:00", 
   "description": "", 
   "id": 1242, 
   "name": "Linux_test", 
   "state": "poweredOff"
   }, 
   {
    "creation_time": "2023-06-06T18:31:37.532826+00:00", 
    "description": "Snapshot TEST", 
    "id": 1243, "name": "Patching_Linux2023-06-06", 
    "state": "poweredOff"
   }
   ]
  }
}
```

I need to take into consideration that I might have several snapshots.
I have tried to delete using the following Ansible task (at first I do not concentrate onto the snapshot age):

**The first shot was :**

```
- name: Remove old snapshots
  vmware_guest_snapshot:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname_uni }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    datacenter: myvcenter
    validate_certs: no
    #name: "{{ inventory_hostname |upper }}"
    folder: "{{ vm_folders }}"
    vm_id: "{{ item.item }}"
    snapshot_name: "{{ item.name }}"
    state: absent
  delegate_to: "{{vcenter_launcher_uni }}"
  loop: "{{ snapshots_info.name }}"
  when: item.name is search('Patching_Linux') 
   tags:
    - clean_patching_snap
```

I have tried other stuffs with loop and with_items conditions but I still cannot figure out how to access all the snapshot names.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be done:

**List the snaphsots**

````
```
- name: Find all sanpshots
  vmware_guest_snapshot_info:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname_uni }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    datacenter: myvcenter
    validate_certs: no
    name: "{{ inventory_hostname |upper }}"
    folder: "{{ vm_folders }}"
  delegate_to: "{{vcenter_launcher_uni }}"
  register: snapshots_info
  tags:
    - list_snap
    - clean_patching_snap```
````

**Remove snapshot containing a specific pattern in their name:**

````
```
- name: Remove old snapshots
  vmware_guest_snapshot:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname_uni }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    datacenter: myvcenter
    validate_certs: no
    name: "{{ inventory_hostname |upper }}"
    folder: "{{ vm_folders }}"
    snapshot_name: "{{ item.name }}"
    state: absent
  delegate_to: "{{vcenter_launcher_uni }}"
  loop: "{{ snapshots_info.guest_snapshots.snapshots }}"
  when: item.name is search('MyPatternName')```
````

I am still stucked in also selecting those which are more than a define number of days.

adding this is not helping :
`
and (ansible_date_time.epoch - (item.creation_time | int)) > 4 * 86400)

```
Something like this will probably work but I am stucked with the exact syntax

'{{ (( ansible_date_time.iso8601 | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')) - (item.creation_time | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')) > (4 * 24 * 60 * 60) and item.name is search('Patching_Linux') }}'
It gives an error
```